# Annotation aspect for both Class Level and Method Level in Spring Boot (NullPointerException)

Tags: spring-boot, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

I am just facing interesting issue when I want to create an aspect for annotation like `@Transactional`.

Here is the controller and annotation:

```java
@RestController
@SimpleAnnotation
public class HelloController{
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HelloController.class);
    
    @GetMapping("/hello")
    @SimpleAnnotation(isAllowed=true)
    public String helloController(){
        final String methodName = "helloController";
        callAnotherMerhod();
        LOGGER.info("HelloController for method : {}", methodName);
        return "Hello";
    }

    private void callAnotherMethod(){

    }
}
```

```java
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
public @interface SimpleAnnotation {

    boolean isAllowed() default false;
}
```

Aspect for that annotation is here:

```java
@Aspect
@Component
public class SimpleAspect {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SimpleAspect.class);

    @Around(value = "@within(simpleAnnotation) || @annotation(simpleAnnotation)", argNames = "simpleAnnotation")
    public Object simpleAnnotation(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint, SimpleAnnotation simpleAnnotation) throws Throwable{
        LOGGER.info("Simple annotation value: {}, ASPECT-LOG {}", simpleAnnotation.isAllowed(),proceedingJoinPoint.getSignature().getName());
        return proceedingJoinPoint.proceed();
    }
}
```

When I run the application and hit the http://localhost:8080/hello , everything is fine:

```
2020-11-09 11:36:48.230  INFO 8479 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.s.springaop.aspects.SimpleAspect       : Simple annotation value: true, ASPECT-LOG helloController

2020-11-09 11:36:48.246  INFO 8479 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.s.s.controller.HelloController         : HelloController for method : helloController
```

However if I removed annotation on the method:

```java
@GetMapping("/hello")
    public String helloController(){
        final String methodName = "helloController";
        callAnotherMethod();
        LOGGER.info("HelloController for method : {}", methodName);
        return "Hello";
    }
```

Then `simpleAnnotation` parameter becomes null, and aspect method throws NullPointerException.

After that, I changed the order of the aspect like the below, it start to work:

```java
@Around(value = " @annotation(simpleAnnotation) || @within(simpleAnnotation)", argNames = "simpleAnnotation")
```

However, in this situation if I remove annotation on class level and just put only the method level, then i am facing the same NPE.

I think, in some way aspect's conditions overwrites the values.

- I tried to separate the class level annotation advice and method level advice, but in that case if i have the annotation on both the class and method level, both advices work (which I do not want)
- I tried to update like this:

```java
    @Around(value = "@within(simpleAnnotation) || @annotation(simpleAnnotation) || @within(simpleAnnotation)", argNames = "simpleAnnotation")
```

This seems to be working, but is it a good solution?

EDIT: This solution is not working also. If I have annotation both on the class and method level and let's say class level annotation value is false, and method's level is true, **then annotation value will be false**.

Comment: I did not debug to find the reason , but I have a solution to the issue .A work around to avoid NPE would be to separate out the pointcut designators (`@within` and `@annotation` ) to two different methods within the same aspect. The `isAllowed` value can be checked and the logic can be executed in another common method. I can add this as an answer if that helps

Comment: @R.G if you add the answer, I would appreciate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To workaround the NPE , you may refactor the pointcut designators (`@within` and `@annotation`) to two different advice methods within the same aspect.

The logic to process based on the `isAllowed` value can be held in a common method and called from both the advice methods.

To illustrate :

```java
@Aspect
@Component
public class SimpleAspect {

    @Around(value = "@annotation(simpleAnnotation) && !@within(my.package.SimpleAnnotation)", argNames = "simpleAnnotation")
    public Object simpleAnnotationOnMethod(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint, SimpleAnnotation simpleAnnotation)
            throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("Simple annotation value:" + simpleAnnotation.isAllowed() + " , ASPECT-LOG :"
                + proceedingJoinPoint.getSignature().getName());
        process(simpleAnnotation);
        return proceedingJoinPoint.proceed();
    }

    @Around(value = "@within(simpleAnnotation)", argNames = "simpleAnnotation")
    public Object simpleAnnotationOnType(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint, SimpleAnnotation simpleAnnotation)
            throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("Simple annotation value:" + simpleAnnotation.isAllowed() + " , ASPECT-LOG :"
                + proceedingJoinPoint.getSignature().getName());
        process(simpleAnnotation);
        return proceedingJoinPoint.proceed();
    }

    private void process(SimpleAnnotation simpleAnnotation) {
        // advice logic
    }
}
```

**Update** : Modified the code as commented by @kriegaex

Comment: However in that case, process method would run two times, if both class and method level annotation exists? I think there is no solution for that ?

Comment: As pointed out by @kriegaex , both conditions holds true in that case and both advice methods would execute  . Either you can control the process logic based on the simpleAnnotation.isAllowed() state or if it helps , based on the the advice method you can differentiate the origin of the call ( i.e type or method ) .

Comment: Got it. I need to find custom solution for that. Thank you ..

Comment: The custom solution is actually simple: Extend the pointcut for `simpleAnnotationOnMethod` as follows: `@annotation(simpleAnnotation) && !@within(my.package.SimpleAnnotation)`. It makes the two advices run in mutually exclusive situations. Besides, you can omit the optional `argNames` stuff and then also don't need to name the annotation `value` anymore. And if your aspect really just returns the result of `proceed()`, why not use a `@Before` advice with less boilerplate?

Answer (score 2):

Your parameter binding is ambiguous due to the `||` because it is a (non-exclusive) OR rather than an XOR, which means that both conditions could be true at the same time. Imagine both the class and the method have an annotation. Which one should be bound?

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26117370/1082681).

I.e. that, just like R.G said, you want to use two separate pointcuts and advices for method- and class-level annotations. You can still factor out duplicate code into a helper method inside the aspect and call it from both advice methods.